# Urn Problem balls distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider an urn with two type of balls white and black with proportionality $p,q$ respectively such that $p+q=1$ we extract balls $n$-time successively with replacement. calculate the probability that the k-th extracted white ball appears on the n-th extraction?
so here is my idea since we have the probability that a white ball appears for the first time at the n-th extraction is $q^{n-1} p$ and the probability to extract exactly k white balls from the n extractions is : $\binom{n}{k} q^{n-k} p^k$ there must be a way to connect this two to find the answer of this question no?

Comment: Hint: you want the probability of [exactly $(k-1)$ whites in $(n-1)$ trials] AND [white on the $n$th trial]

Comment: @Ned so it will be $\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1} q^{n-k} \cdot  p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to have exactly $k-1$ white balls extracted in the first $n-1$ extractions, and then to extract a white ball. This probability is given by
$${{n-1}\choose {k-1}}p^{k-1}q^{n-1-(k-1)} \cdot p={{n-1}\choose {k-1}}p^{k}q^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 1):

The approach is correct, but not quite there.

You want the probability for obtaining **$k-1$ white among the first $n-1$ draws**, and a white ball on the subsequent draw (and thus it will be the $k$-th white ball on the $n$-th draw).

Comment: but why are we using the binomial coefficient doesnt that reflect some type of order? meanwhile the extractions are done with replacement so order doesnt really matter?

Comment: The binomial coefficient reflects the fact that we are counting all possible combinations of extractions in which $k-1$ balls are extracted in the first $n-1$ attempts.

Comment: Order does not matter, so we must count all possible orders of selection of places for the white balls.